# step function in cucumber capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cucumber, capybara

I try to get string from scenario and set in to step definition. But its not working.

My scenario is

```
Scenario: Save Contact with empty field in setting page
    Given I logged in
    When remove "contact" manitary field
    Then I click save button
    Then I should see message
```

and my step definition is

```
When /^remove "([^"]*)" manitary field$/ do |n|
  rows = all('##{n}-mapping-table tbody tr')
  rows.each do |raw|
    within raw do
      find('.remove_nested_fields').click 
      sleep 1
    end
  end
  find("##{n}-mapping-table thead tr th.add-new .insert_in_table").click
end
```

the error message is `An invalid or illegal string was specified (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError)`

I dont know what error is here.

Thanks for your advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with

```
rows = all("##{n}-mapping-table tbody tr")
```

Note the double quotes :)

Comment: oh. simple mistake. Thank you :)